# Passing manual properties to sonarqube while using gradle

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, sonarqube

I am trying to implement SonarQube in an AWS CodePipeline. To this end I am trying to follow [this blogpost](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/devops/integrating-sonarcloud-with-aws-codepipeline-using-aws-codebuild/), where they are handing over login information and other properties via command line using maven:

```
- mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=$LOGIN -Dsonar.host.url=$HOST -Dsonar.projectKey=$Project -Dsonar.organization=$Organization
```

Since I am using gradle, I tried the according command from the [docs](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-gradle/):

```
gradle sonar -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin
```

to access my local SonarQube server, but I keep receiving:

```
Task '.login=admin' not found in root project 'gradle_test'.
```

It works completly fine when adding the following to the gradle.properties

```
systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
systemProp.sonar.login=admin
systemProp.sonar.password=admin
```

but sadly not when trying to hand over the properties.

I am using Windows and added SonarQube via

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "4.3.0.3225"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sonar.password` has been deprecated if you are using the latest version of SonarQube. We should be passing an authentication token to the gradle or maven based scanner.

If using version 9.x:

`gradle sonar -Dsonar.login=yourAuthenticationToken`

If using latest version:

`gradle sonar -Dsonar.token=yourAuthenticationToken`

[SonarQube 9.x](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-gradle/)

[SonarQube latest](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-gradle/)

The authentication token can be created under the account's security configuration.

[image]

Comment: I know, sadly the same error occurs for all properties.

Comment: What is the SonarQube version?

Comment: SonarQube: 4.3.0.3225